# cmake one module include another one

Tags: cmake

For a cmake toolchain file, A.toolchain.cmake, I want to include B.cmake, which only has some variables set. Two cmake file lay in the same folder.
But cmake output error, cannot find B.cmake.

> CMake Error at /Users/robert/workspace/cpp/CLIon/rSock/xbuild/cmake/Darwin_x86_64.toolchain.cmake:12 (include):
>     include could not find load file:
>      /Users/robert/workspace/cpp/CLIon/rSock/xbuild/build/Darwin_x86_64/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/xbuild/cmake/base.cmake

I tried many ways, relative or absolute path, or set as module. They just don't work. But if I put include in CMakelists.txt, it works.
Why? Only cmakelists.txt can include other cmake files?

```
#include("./base.cmake")

#set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/xbuild/cmake")
#include(base)

include(${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/xbuild/cmake/base.cmake)
```

Comment: Judging on error, it looks for CMake files in the build dir. This is strange. What commands are you running?

Comment: @arrowd cmake -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=path/to/toolchain.cmake

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using [CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR.html):

```
include("${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/base.cmake")
```